# Old light fixture has 3 sets of black, white and copper. It keeps tripping breaker when installed. Not sure what to do

Tags: electrical, light-fixture

I’m installing a new light fixture to replace an old ceiling fan light fixture. When I removed the old fixture there are 3 sets of black, white, and copper wires in white casings. My new fixture does not have a fan and only has the standard black, white and copper wires. When I wire them, they immediately trip the breaker. How do I fix this or find out which wire goes to what?

Comment: Please post the pictures you took before disconnecting everything.

Comment: Would it be safe to assume that you disconnected everything, and then when wiring your new fixture you connected all the blacks together, all the whites together and all the bare coppers together?

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of all the boxes involved please?

Comment: We will need a photo or description of the wires at the switch you probably have a switch loop so when you connected everything together and turn the switch on you create a dead short tripping the breaker. If one of the whites has black tape or is marked a different color that is probably the cable going to the switch.

Answer (score 1):

one of those white wires goes to the switch
one of those black wires comes from the switch

You need to figure out which is which and connect the white wire goes to to the switch to the black wires (this white wire should have black paint or tape on it)
connect the black wire that comes from the switch to the lamp, and (using a short piece of wire) connect the other white wires to the other lamp terminal.